# What would be the appropriate learning path given these circumstances?

Tags: computer-architecture

I've recently been trying to learn to program in python but I’ve been experiencing this overwhelming feeling of a desire to understand the underlying structure behind everything I’m doing. I want to be able to understand how computers work from the ground up, how hardware and software relate to one another and develop an intuition for their potential. I'd also like to know how all these languages that build on top of each other all rely on the same fundamentals and what those fundamentals are. Only then do I think I’ll feel comfortable and satisfied learning and working on a more superficial abstraction which I consider python to be.

Can any of you recommend a path I should take in order to satisfy this need? Whether that be a particular order of learning certain topics or more specifically any book, video, course that you might consider appropriate given my situation.

Thank you,

Mango164

Comment: The royal road is obtaining a BA in Computer Science.

Answer (score 1):

A project I would recommend is the [NandToTetris Project](http://nand2tetris.org/). It takes you from understanding the basic logic gates through VonNeumann architecture to how Operating Systems work.